# Process Builder giving error The flow failed to access the value for [example] because it hasn't been set or assigned

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, process-builder

I have a process builder which is giving error:  unable to find field dataType for complex reference.

In server log :The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Product2.Vendor_Agreement_Rule__c because it hasn't been set or assigned
I have maintained a condition whereby checking the value from where it is getting the value from a foreign field. checking it as

1) isNull boolean false 2) equals boolean true

that field is referencing to some other parent field where values are there
Still the error is coming in the process builder. Kindly let me know how to remove the same.

Answer (score -1):

Have you queried it from the sObject variable you passed in?  Initially, only the sObject's values are available...  So, if you want to access it's parent sObject's values, you'll need to query them first.  This is the same behavior you'd experience in a trigger.

To resolve this, I recommend using a Quick Lookup item in your flow.

Comment: thanks for the update , i have updated the process builder with a formula check regarding the boolean value , now the criteria are not met.Is the formula field a right way to check the same.

Comment: I think a formula field is perfectly valid if it's a complex boolean.    You should be able to handle most logic in the filters within the lookup/assignment.

Comment: but still i am facing the same error.

Comment: Okay, you'll need to break this down.   My other recommendation is to create a Screen component and display each variable in a Display Text box.  this way, you can check each step of the way and essentially "debug" your flow to see where the breakage occurs.   Otherwise, you'll need to post more information.   Also, if you are using Process Builder, I recommend supplmening it with a Flow (much more robust).

Comment: The OP was referring to Process Builder, not Visual Flow - there are no screen elements and no Fast Lookups, just this neverending error.